# Communicating with identical IP addresses on many distinct networks

Tags: windows, ip, nic

I would like to be able to connect to a small group of networked hardware (let's call it a *Rack*) via a switch and a NIC in a Windows 10 Pro computer.  The system hardware has fixed 192.168.0.x addresses and they are  accessed by a computer's browser (typically Firefox). The hardware expects the computer's NIC to be at 192.168.0.1.  This I know how to do.
[image: image of simple fixed IP connection to one rack]

For QC test purposes I would like to be able to use a single PC to connect to multiple such Racks.  I guess this requires either:
A NIC based solution
[image: a Multi-NIC topology]

or a Router  based solution.

[image: router-based topology]

The KEY problem is that the corresponding IP addresses are fixed and identical at every rack, including the IP of the computer which needs to appear 192.168.0.1 at for every rack.

This poses a real problem for FTP of files from the racks to the computer and for browser's connections to specific rack and component WebUIs.

Is either of these solutions possible?  What would be required to implement the viable solution?  What pitfalls are likely?

Comment: Are you a profesionnal administrator? If not you should go to superuser.com. 
What eludes me is why can't you just connect your PC as 192.168.0.1 to the switch and all the other devices using 192.168.0.x also to the switch?

Comment: You need a picture of what you're trying to do... If you're using a switch, why do you need multiple NICs in the PC?

Comment: I hope the improved explanation and images help clarify what I want to do.  The problem is that  since this is a QC test  nothing should be changed after the test is complete OR I would just change the IP's and change them back.

Comment: Probably not, but it would be a trivial NAT ruleset in Linux. I suspect, any advanced routers can do this configuration. I could insert your images into your post, but they are too big. Could you please resize them to 50%? Anyways, a reopen vote casted (total 5 are needed to reopen your question).

Comment: Yep, NAT is your friend here. Set a NATing router (which may be a Linux box or may be a dedicated HW router) in front of them.

Comment: Updated text for clarity in  a few spots, and to reduce the size of the images